# Getting the Twitter stream on Heroku with Django App

Tags: django, heroku, celery, background-process

I need to constantly monitor a Twitter stream using Heroku.  Basically what I want to do is start the monitoring process up and never have it stop.  I was looking into celery, but from my understanding of it, it looks like a user initiated or short term process adds tasks to a queue that are then processed by another queue.  This is different model than having a background process constantly monitoring  a Twitter stream.  What would be the best way to monitor a Twitter stream for a Django app on Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything in Django that can run in the background like that. It's certainly one of the limitations of living in the web-app sandbox.

If you have access to your server in Heroku (?) you could write your own script/application along the lines of [this tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python.ars) and daemonize using Supervisord.

if not:
Celery has a nice [periodic scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).  If you're okay with polling instead of streaming (API), I might just use the twitter REST API and the scheduler in Celery to periodically poll and update.  It's helpful to match the scheduling with the rate limits as well.

Comment: Can I schedule an infinitely long task?

Comment: yes I guess you could start a task that doesn't [end](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits). To have good uptime, you'd have to get clever about monitoring it and restarting it if it dies or errors out. Some of the facilities to do something like that are there;  perhaps you could have some other periodic task that inspects the active tasks, and starts a new one if necessary. The subtask, taskset, or chord features might be useful as well. Its not something that is supported 'out of the box' however and might take some time to implement correctly.

Comment: Note that if you're running it on Heroku, you can use their scheduler instead of celery.  I did this for an application of mine which is documented <a href="http://www.princesspolymath.com/princess_polymath/?p=521">here</a>